# Spring batch 3.0.2 dependency with javax.batch.runtime.JobInstance

Tags: spring-batch, java-6

Updates:

After adding javax.batch-api-1.0.jar file, the below exception is gone and the application is up an running.

Origianl Post

I have been using Java 6 along with Spring batch and Integration for a year by now.
Application is a stand alone java application using Java 1.6.

Since the version of spring batch is so outdated, I am trying to update the libraries today.
I upgraded,

- Spring framework from 3.2 to 4.1.2
- Spring batch from 2.1 to 3.0.2
- Spring Integration from 2.2 to 4.1

Due to the upgrade, I added a new jar file which is Spring-retry-1.1.jar

After the upgrade, I am having below exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.batch.runtime.JobInstance
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

It looks like spring batch core 3.0.2 does not support Java SE6 for me. It looks like Java EE7 package. However when I dig the spring batch document, it says it support Java 6,7,8.

Does anybody knows what is going on Spring batch core 3.0.2 with Java version?

Comment: If you aren't running JSR-352 batch jobs, that should be an optional dependency.  Can you please post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a java version issue - it looks your missing jars on your run-time class path

How are you managing your dependencies? The spring batch 3.0.2 depends on a jar --> Javax.batch API that contains the class in question. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.batch/javax.batch-api

For a list of full dependencies check out --> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/3.0.2.RELEASE

Note the dependency is not optional. The Spring JobInstance  class implements the JobInstance  and as such is a required dependency.

Class JobInstance

```
    All Implemented Interfaces:
    java.io.Serializable, javax.batch.runtime.JobInstance
```